# Resources with large images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multilingual

I am working on Multilingual C# windows forms application. I am using languages such as Japanese, Chinese, Thai and Korean.
 So I am loading resource files such as Resources.ja-JP.resx, Resources.zn-CH.resx, Resources.th-TH.resx and Resources.ko-KR.resx.

We are using big images in our project which are loaded into those corresponding resources. So the resource dll's size is around 400 MB each.

I am trying to run the application in x86 Debug mode but I am getting "out of Memory exception" while changing the language. I did lots of searches but everyone is telling that it is because of very big dll's.

Did anyone faced the same scenario. Please let me know.

Comment: Dont put bitmaps as they are very large. Scale down them first . Create small images and put in resources and show where ever necessary. In case there is requirement of large HD images to display. Render them from Disk. dont put them in Dll instead put their path to render. Dont forget to dispose as well.

Comment: Call stack FTW!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the out of memory exception because of the images? 400MB does not sound very large for today's systems.
Remove all images and see if the problem persists.

Otherwise, as @Ramankingdom suggested, move the images out of the resources. Just create a folder called images with subfolders for the individual languages. This way you can just replace the subfolder with the .NET current culture and you should be fine.

Comment: "Out of memory" is very often thrown by GDI+ when dealing with images with large _pixel dimensions_. Even if you have plenty of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.